# How to verify Specific field is not empty in a table which is updating frequently using Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium-ide

I have table which is frequently updating and all the values may change when an update comes to the table. i want to verify whether specific columns have values or not.
 [Table has four comuns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/511S4.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first identify the cells. Ideally with xpath:

```
//tr[1]/td[1]
```

where numbers will point to row for tr tag and column for td tag. If you have more tables on the page, use more specific xpath:

```
//div[contains(@class,'commodities')]/descendant::tr[1]/td[1]
```

then it is good to store text of the cell to a variable and compare it to what you want

```
storetext | //tr[1]/td[1] | textVar
```

then you can compare if there is an empty string, for example

```
verifyEval | storedVars['textVar'].length > 0 | true
```

and this will fail the test if there is no value or pass the test when there is some value.

or you can each result echo to the log by storing the result and echo it as true/false.

```
storeEval | storedVars['textVar'].length > 0 | isThereAValue
echo | Is there a value? ${isThereAValue}
```

which will echo true or false.

Question is, what you want to do with the value if there is something. If you want to do different steps, then I can recommend to you to use Selblocks for Selenium IDE, which will allow to process conditions and cycles or the Selenium WebDriver. Then you can process different part of your test based on the content of the table. I can imagine, you can process whole table in the cycle for each row at once.

I can add some hints if you question will be more specific.